# Undesired effect on Font size and lines spacing in paragraph and ToC after including unnumbered chapters

Tags: sectioning, chapters

When I include the unnumbered chapter; abstract, acknowledgment, the font size and line spacing of the entire document from ToC to the last chapter are changing in a haphazard way. However, if I removed those lines, its display rendering is perfect. Hope some can help. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage %Clear any float page and new page start from right side
\pagenumbering{roman}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}%sections numbering upto 2
 %Unnumbered chapter start
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%before  \listof...
\include{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}%before  \listof...
\include{acknowledgement}
 %Unnumbered chapter start

% Add table of content, figures,acronyms and symbols
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables 
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage %Clear any float page and new page start from right side
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{introduction}
\end{document}
```

When I include unnumbered chapters, the output is,
[image]
When I do not include the chapter, the output is,

[image]

Comment: Please replace `\include{introduction}` with something we can use. We do not have that file.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You don't show the contents of the abstract or introduction, both of which are accessed with `\include`.  Look into those files to see if there is a change of font (which would also change the baseline height), and if there is, add at the beginning of each file a line `\begingroup`, and at the end, `\endgroup`.  These commanbds will localize the font changes.

Comment: As Barbara says, changes are that you are trying to use say, `\Large` as a macro, aka `\Large{text}`, but `\Large` does not take arguments, so in `\Large{text} text` both `\text` will have the same size

Comment: Next time please remember that those trying to help you need a full example they can copy to their systems as is, and be able to test your code with no modifications.

Comment: @barbara beeton, My abstract and acknowledgment, and tex files have usual chapter sections as follows, \chapter*{Introduction}
\ClearShipoutPicture%Its used to provide border for unnumbered sections like abstract and acknowledgment
\section{Overview}
para text go here.
and usual subsection and etc
%baseline is not used%

\chapter*{\centering Acknowledgement}

Comment: "Usual" chapters and sections are not closed environments.  This means that an undelimited font change (and many other global specifications) will persist into the next one unless explicitly reversed (or delimited).  Regarding my suggestion for delimiting the scope, @daleif's suggestion is better than mine.  `{\Large text}` is how this is most appropriately handled (if that's how a font was changed).

Comment: @Ram -- The code you've shown in your comment is much better added to the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and daleif , Thank you guys. The problem is exactly as you both mentioned ,the foot name \large \textbf{name} in acknowledgment, it supposed to be  {\large \textbf{name}}. You are awesome.